# How can I find the page where ill do the changes in angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It is a completed project, I am asked to solve an issue.

There are *3 select boxes*, and all have different names. First select box's *name* is `nameSelectBox162572640796915`, *second one* is `nameSelectBox16257264317217`, *third one* `nameSelectBox162572643286379`

There are *3 value* options for *select boxes*, they are *"1", "2"*, or *"3"*, If  i choose 1 or 2 or 3, whatever i choose wont be selectable for others,

On *developer tools*, i am able to do it.

For example: whatever i choose in first *SelectBox*, i write this code for the second,
so that value wont be selectable for that *select box*

```
var source = document.getElementsByName("nameSelectBox162572640796915")[0];
source.value
document.getElementsByName("nameSelectBox16257264317217")[0].options[source.value].setAttribute("disabled","disabled")
```

the page where i look at it is `http://localhost:3000/#/form`

But i cant find that page, and i dont know where to write that code which worked for me...
How can I do it?

Comment: Can you provide the source code of your complete project?

Comment: I could but i dont know which page i should add here.. it has many pages...I dont know where this part is included

Comment: Now I found the page. Which one should I add here? there is form.html, and formCTRL.js ? and formCTRL.js has 800 lines of code..

Comment: Did you publish the site on your system using IIS by any chance? If no root directory was specified, I think the files would reside in C:\inetpub\wwwroot.

When publishing it from VS, have a look at the web publish dialogue, maybe change it to a place that would make more sense to you.

Comment: Well this is made by the company i work as an intern at. I can see the pages on my local(localhost..) when i type `gulp serve` the app opens. there are many pages in the project. I dont know if i am too lazy or idiot to understand this, I question myself sometimes... 

Btw i mean i can open the app and see the code, but i just dont know where to do this change which i am asked to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. Set the options to be created through ng-repeat, then use ng-disabled to test for which numbers have been selected already

```js
angular.module('myApp', [
  // myApp dependencies (controllers, etc.) injected here...
  'myApp.controllers'
]);

angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.select1 = '';
  $scope.select2 = '';
  $scope.select3 = '';
  $scope.numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

}])
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<select ng-model="select1">
  <option ng-repeat='num in numbers' ng-disabled="(select2 == num || select3 == num)">{{num}}</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="select2">
  <option ng-repeat='num in numbers' ng-disabled="(select1 == num || select3 == num)">{{num}}</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="select3">
  <option ng-repeat='num in numbers' ng-disabled="(select2 == num || select1 == num)">{{num}}</option>
</select>


</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Btw can i ask you a question Sir? I am an intern at a company, trying to improve my skills, in javascript,react,react-native. How should i study, I feel like i am too slow...i want to be helpful for the company , but i dont think i am. I'm 30 and made a career transition tho

Comment: Did this code work for you? If so, please consider accepting it as the answer. To your other question  - take online courses, practice on your own and learn from this website. Everyone feels slow and inadequate when they're learning a new language - especially on the job like you are. Don't get discouraged, and don't feel like everyone else gets it but you. Everyone goes through this but not everyone sticks it out. Study hard in the beginning to get a running start. Good luck

Comment: I am sure your code will be helpful, i just figure out where to paste this code in the project.(its a bit complicated). Thank you so much for giving me courage. I appreciate it.